# Find the index which partitions the arrays into 2 subarrays whose absolute difference of their sums is minimized

Tags: binary-search, partition, sub-array, prefix-sum

We have to find an index 'x' such that the absolute difference between

> (A[1]+A[2]+..+A[x]) and (A[x+1]+A[x+2]+..+A[n]) for some x ,
>
> is minimized.

I came across this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55999814/partition-the-array-with-minimal-difference)

Here the author has asked to minimize the produc of the subarrays, so in my question, I can take the logarithm of the array elements and the questions turn out to be equivalent to what I have asked

I was thinking of calculating the prefix sum array and the perform binary search on it. But the array elements go up to 10^19, 
and storing the sum may give a memory limit error.